# Positioning and extending an element under others

Tags: css, layout

I have a website with typical blog layout - one post under another. I would like to place a div that would be like a 'pipe' joining them all - from the top one to the one at the bottom.

[THIS](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10530011/web-nie-usuwac/stackoverflow-css-pipe.png) picture might explain help you understand my idea. (sorry for handwriting)

I were thinking for example of wrapping whole post area inside of div, resizing it horizontally to smaller, fixed width and centering but could I do that without affecting the contents? I want just the background of that 'pipe' to appear.

Thank you

Comment: do you need to retain the transparency?

Comment: @Michelle no, there is no transparency. I've added it on the drawing just to picture better what I want. If it would be achieved easier by placing div between every node It's ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap it in a div, and absolutely position the pipe behind it.
Something like:

```
.wrapper {
  poisition: relative;    
}

.pipe {
  position: absolute;
  top:5%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 90%;
}
```

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/eMKaW/